# "There is no device with id [generic] in wurfl" in Zend implementation of WURFL

Tags: zend-framework, wurfl

I've followed the guide in the Zend documentation:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.http.user-agent.html

And included all the configs in my application.ini like this:

```
; Mobile device detection
resources.useragent.storage.adapter                                     = "Session"
resources.useragent.wurflapi.wurfl_api_version                          = "1.1"
resources.useragent.wurflapi.wurfl_lib_dir                              = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library/wurfl-php-1.3.1/WURFL/"
resources.useragent.wurflapi.wurfl_config_array.cache.provider          = "file"
resources.useragent.wurflapi.wurfl_config_array.cache.dir               = APPLICATION_PATH "/../data/wurfl/cache/" 
resources.useragent.wurflapi.wurfl_config_array.wurfl.main-file         = APPLICATION_PATH "/../data/wurfl/wurfl.xml"
resources.useragent.wurflapi.wurfl_config_array.wurfl.patches           = APPLICATION_PATH "/../data/wurfl/web_browsers_patch.xml"
resources.useragent.wurflapi.wurfl_config_array.persistence.provider    = "file"
resources.useragent.wurflapi.wurfl_config_array.persistence.dir.dir     = APPLICATION_PATH "/../data/wurfl/cache/"
```

The first time I run my app before the data/wurfl/cache is populated, I get this fatal error:

```
Cannot send headers; headers already sent in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/thebirdy.com/library/wurfl-php-1.3.1/WURFL/Xml/VersionIterator.php, line 29
```

The second time I run my app, and every subsequent time, I get the application error:

```
There is no device with id [generic] in wurfl
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/thebirdy.com/library/wurfl-php-1.3.1/WURFL/CustomDeviceRepository.php(70): WURFL_CustomDeviceRepository->getDevice('generic')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your wurfl setting in `application.ini` does not need to include that many settings. Just having the following is enough:

```
resources.useragent.wurflapi.wurfl_api_version = "1.1"
resources.useragent.wurflapi.wurfl_lib_dir = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library/wurfl-php-1.1/WURFL/"
resources.useragent.wurflapi.wurfl_config_file = APPLICATION_PATH "/configs/wurfl-config.php"
```